# Instant to Unix timestamp

Tags: java, java-time

How should I convert an `Instant` to a unix timestamp string with decimals for sub-second precision?

Test cases are:

```
@Test
public void toStringUnixTime() throws Exception {
    assertEquals("0", TimeUtils.toStringUnixTime(Instant.EPOCH));
    assertEquals("1491327940.619", TimeUtils.toStringUnixTime(Instant.ofEpochMilli(1491327940619L)));
    assertEquals("1491327940.000012345", TimeUtils.toStringUnixTime(Instant.ofEpochSecond(1491327940, 12345)));
}
```

Proposal which doesn't quite work (has always trailing 0s, has always the dot)

```
public static String toStringUnixTime(Instant i){
    return i.getEpochSecond() + "." + String.format("%09d", i.getNano());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is hard because the java.time.* API deliberately chose not to provide a conversion to `BigDecimal` in `Instant` or `Duration`. The rationale is that at some point in the future, value types will be added to Java and there will likely be a new, much more efficient, decimal type.

Currently the answer by Philipp is fine. Just to add that it can be wrapped in a `TemporalQuery` as follows:

```
public static TemporalQuery<String> UNIX_STRING = TimeUtils::toStringUnixTime;

private static String toStringUnixTime(TemporalAccessor temporal) {
  Instant i = Instant.from(temporal);
  BigDecimal nanos = BigDecimal.valueOf(i.getNano(), 9);
  BigDecimal seconds = BigDecimal.valueOf(i.getEpochSecond());
  BigDecimal total = seconds.add(nanos);
  DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#########");
  return df.format(total);
}
```

Now we have this query, we can change the original code as follows:

```
@Test
public void toStringUnixTime() throws Exception {
  assertEquals("0", Instant.EPOCH.query(UNIX_STRING));
  assertEquals("1491327940.619", Instant.ofEpochMilli(1491327940619L).query(UNIX_STRING));
  assertEquals("1491327940.000012345", Instant.ofEpochSecond(1491327940, 12345).query(UNIX_STRING));
}
```

Using queries like this is often a neater way of writing code than using static utility classes. The query also works with `OffsetDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: Am I right in thinking, that calling this on any other `TemporalAccessor` (like LocalDate for example) will fail, but only at runtime (compiles just fine)? Isn't the static method approach giving you more type safety?

Comment: It will work on any type that `Instant.from()` can convert, `ZonedDateTime` and `OffsetDateTime` for example. But yes, it will fail in other cases like `LocalDate`. Depend on what you feel is important.

Comment: What happened with value types? Looked into java 10 ... still not there ...

Comment: Value types are a big task. They are still being worked on and will be for a number of years.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit I came up with

```
public static String toStringUnixTime(Instant i){
    BigDecimal nanos = BigDecimal.valueOf(i.getNano(), 9);
    BigDecimal seconds = BigDecimal.valueOf(i.getEpochSecond());
    BigDecimal total = seconds.add(nanos);
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#########");
    return df.format(total);
}
```

This seems suboptimal, but does the job.